# Why do some text editors offer to end your file with a line break? Why is that important?

Tags: macos, text-editors, textmate, bbedit

Why do some text editors such as BBEdit and Textmate offer to end your file with a newline (line break)? Why is that important?

Are there any caveats to not ending a file with a line break?

Answer (score 4):

Some Unix-style text processing commands may produce unexpected behavior if the last line does not end with a newline.  For example, `wc -l` counts the number of lines in a file, but it does so essentially by counting the newline characters, so the last "line" isn't counted.  Some other programs also miss the last line if it's not terminated by a newline.

Comment: As another example, if you used `cat` to combine two files and the last line of the first file did not end with a newline, then the last line of the first file and the first line of the second file would be joined as one line. The Unix convention is that a newline is a line terminator, not a line separator.